# ax.set_yticklabels shows ticks as long decimals

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, decimal

I want to modify the font size of a plot with `ax.set_yticklabels`. 
However, I get a weird number with a lot of decimal places.

My code is somewhat like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.subplot()
ax.plot(np.arange(10), np.arange(10)*0.1)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(10)*0.1)
ax.set_yticklabels(np.arange(10)*0.1, fontdict={'size':'14'})
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I get rid of the long decimal in the tick labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ax.set_yticklabels(['{:.2f}'.format(a) for a in np.arange(0,11,0.1)], fontdict={'size':'14'})
```

This is due to the conversion between float and strings. You can control the format by doing the conversion yourself, for example using [string formatting functions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatspec).